# QIIME2 error when running diversity analyses

Tags: python, distance, qiime

I am running `qiime2-2022.8`, on my Linux laptop (`Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64`). Installed via conda.

I went through entire moving pictures tutorial, everything seemed to run fine. Now I tried my own data (and I also had this same error when trying to run Atacama soil tutorial data), and I'm running these commands:

```bash
qiime diversity core-metrics-phylogenetic \
  --i-phylogeny rooted-tree.qza \
  --i-table table.qza  \
  --p-sampling-depth 700 \
  --m-metadata-file sample-metadata.tsv  \
  --output-dir core-metrics-results
```

and getting this error message:

```
Plugin error from diversity:

  Command '['ssu', '-i', '/tmp/qiime2/mike/data/67d50ad2-ce55-4192-9f83-c4254b86110c/data/feature-table.biom', '-t', '/tmp/qiime2/mike/data/7b8f5914-09aa-4e99-a53f-0e6310557047/data/tree.nwk', '-m', 'unweighted', '-o', '/tmp/q2-LSMatFormat-alcain3f']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Debug info has been saved to /tmp/qiime2-q2cli-err-x3td01k5.log
```

Can anyone help?

I expected to get diversity artifacts that I could then convert to visualizations of the stats.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this answer in the QIIME2 -- it was related to how the Unifrac libraries were installed.
I ran this:

\export UNIFRAC_USE_GPU=N

and now it works!